# Cannot install openssl-devel on redhat 7.3?

Tags: openssl, redhat

I am trying to install openssl-dev package (In order to use it in PACT rust implementation) on "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3", which contains "OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013" installed version but not its include files as far as I can tell. I tried various options to install it through yum was failed (For example, I tried http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-install-and-update-openssl-on-centos-6-centos-7/). I am working behind proxy, but I doesn’t seems to be the problem (I can install other things and already add it into /etc/yum.conf). When I am running:

> yum install openssl-devel

I get:

```
    This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
    ...
    No package openssl-devel available.
```

I found some workaround with building locally, but it takes a lot of preparing  work (setting OPENSSL_LIB_DIR, OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR, OPENSSL_STATIC & OPENSSL_DIR environment variables) so it will be very helpful, since I will recreate replacement workstation soon (so you can assume that I will discard any grabge that I already put in the system).

Thanks, Assaf

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't clear enough about it, but this is first step for development of software - PACT rust implementation (https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-reference/tree/master/rust). Per my understanding, this falls under "software tools commonly used by programmers", but maybe I am wrong :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a valid Red Hat Enterprise Linux subscription before you can download any binary RPM packages.

If this is for development purposes, you can perhaps use a development subscription (you will have to read the subscription terms to check if your use case qualifies):

- [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Download](https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/download/)

After that, you might be able to use your Customer Portal login to enroll your existing system, using `subscription-manager register`.  (I have never done this and there might be restrictions which prevent this.)

Furthermore, the person who tasked you with this work hopefully has access to Red Hat subscriptions, too.

If the subscription route does not work for you and you absolutely need to proceed at any cost (even at the risk of breaking your existing system), you can download the matching `openssl-devel` version from a [CentOS mirror](http://mirror.centos.org/). However, this will almost certainly make the system unsupported (which of course only matters if you activate a subscription later).

Comment: I afraid that this is this the problem, but while I have techincally the a subscription from Amdocs, it will take a time. Anyway, thanks